# tailwindCSS - How to add a Button on a carousel slide?

Tags: html, css, tailwind-css

I have been playing around with this Carousel [created by Tom Smedley](https://codepen.io/TheTomS/pen/eYNJZOx?editors=1000#anon-login). He uses AlpineJS and TailwindCSS. It's really a gorgeous design.

I have re-edited the code pen linked above to fit my issue.

[Here is my version of the sandbox which replicates the problem](https://codepen.io/tac0man9224/pen/bGWMvaK?editors=1000)

I have added a `LEARN MORE` button for each carousel slide, however the button is hidden behind the `<h1>` content headers. To test, I have added a hover effect on the button to change color, but the button cannot be hovered.

- How can I fix the button to be infront of the `<h1>` text and locate itself at the bottom left of the `<h1>` header? I can fix this issue with setting button margins but due to the nature of the text length on each slide this is not a good solution.

Here is a screenshot of what I'm trying to aim for:[image]

I don't care if the button goes outside of the slide (due to h1 text length), I just want it to be at the bottom left of the header text.

I have tried many attempts using flex, grids, etc... But I keep struggling. Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put all your `<button>` tags inside the `<h1>` tags, and insert the following CSS:

```
 h1 > button {
      position: absolute !important;
      left: 0;
      top: 100%;
      font-size: 1rem !important;
    }
```

I've also included a snippet. Run it in fullscreen mode:

```js
function carousel() {
        return {
            active: 0,
            init() {
                var flkty = new Flickity(this.$refs.carousel, {
                    wrapAround: true,
                });
                flkty.on("change", (i) => (this.active = i));
            },
        };
    }

    function carouselFilter() {
        return {
            active: 0,
            changeActive(i) {
                this.active = i;

                this.$nextTick(() => {
                    let flkty = Flickity.data(
                        this.$el.querySelectorAll(".carousel")[i]
                    );
                    flkty.resize();

                    console.log(flkty);
                });
            },
        };
    }
```

```css
.flickity-viewport {
      height: 500px !important;
    }

    h1 > button {
      position: absolute !important;
      left: 0;
      top: 100%;
      font-size: 1rem !important;
      pointer-events: auto; /* This is part of EDIT 2 */
    }
```

```html
<html>

<head></head>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/flickity@2/dist/flickity.pkgd.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/alpinejs/alpine@v2.x.x/dist/alpine.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/flickity@2/dist/flickity.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/tailwindcss@1.2.0/dist/tailwind.min.css">

<body>
    <main
      class="min-h-screen bg-black text-white flex items-center justify-center"
      x-data="carouselFilter()"
    >
      <div class="container grid grid-cols-1">
        <div class="flex py-12 justify-center">
          <a
            class="
              px-2
              text-lg
              uppercase
              font-bold
              tracking-widest
              hover:text-white
            "
            :class="{ 'text-gray-800': active != 0 }"
            href="#"
            @click.prevent="changeActive(0)"
            >Lorem Ipsum</a
          >
        </div>

        <div
          class="row-start-2 col-start-1"
          x-show="active == 0"
          x-transition:enter="transition ease-out duration-300"
          x-transition:enter-start="opacity-0 transform scale-90"
          x-transition:enter-end="opacity-100 transform scale-100"
          x-transition:leave="transition ease-in duration-300"
          x-transition:leave-start="opacity-100 transform scale-100"
          x-transition:leave-end="opacity-0 transform scale-90"
        >
          <div
            class="grid grid-cols-1 grid-rows-1"
            x-data="carousel()"
            x-init="init()"
          >
            <div
              class="
                col-start-1
                row-start-1
                relative
                z-20
                flex
                items-center
                justify-center
                pointer-events-none
              "
            >
              <h1
                class="absolute text-5xl uppercase font-black tracking-widest"
                x-show="active == 0"
                x-transition:enter="transition ease-out duration-300"
                x-transition:enter-start="opacity-0 transform translate-y-12"
                x-transition:enter-end="opacity-100 transform translate-y-0"
                x-transition:leave="transition ease-out duration-300"
                x-transition:leave-start="opacity-100 transform translate-y-0"
                x-transition:leave-end="opacity-0 transform -translate-y-12"
              >
                Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting
                industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy
                text ever since the 1500s
                <button
                  class="
                    border border-white
                    text-white
                    rounded-md
                    px-4
                    py-2
                    m-2
                    transition
                    duration-500
                    ease
                    select-none
                    hover:text-white hover:bg-indigo-600
                    focus:outline-none focus:shadow-outline
                  "
                  x-show="active == 0"
                >
                  LEARN MORE
                </button>
              </h1>

              <h1
                class="absolute text-5xl uppercase font-black tracking-widest"
                x-show="active == 1"
                x-transition:enter="transition ease-out duration-300"
                x-transition:enter-start="opacity-0 transform translate-y-12"
                x-transition:enter-end="opacity-100 transform translate-y-0"
                x-transition:leave="transition ease-out duration-300"
                x-transition:leave-start="opacity-100 transform translate-y-0"
                x-transition:leave-end="opacity-0 transform -translate-y-12"
              >
                It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted
                by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout.
                <button
                  class="
                    border border-white
                    text-white
                    rounded-md
                    px-4
                    py-2
                    m-2
                    transition
                    duration-500
                    ease
                    select-none
                    hover:text-white hover:bg-indigo-600
                    focus:outline-none focus:shadow-outline
                  "
                  x-show="active == 1"
                >
                  LEARN MORE
                </button>
              </h1>
              <h1
                class="absolute text-5xl uppercase font-black tracking-widest"
                x-show="active == 2"
                x-transition:enter="transition ease-out duration-300"
                x-transition:enter-start="opacity-0 transform translate-y-12"
                x-transition:enter-end="opacity-100 transform translate-y-0"
                x-transition:leave="transition ease-out duration-300"
                x-transition:leave-start="opacity-100 transform translate-y-0"
                x-transition:leave-end="opacity-0 transform -translate-y-12"
              >
                There are many variations of passages of Lorem Ipsum available
                <button
                  class="
                    border border-white
                    text-white
                    rounded-md
                    px-4
                    py-2
                    m-2
                    transition
                    duration-500
                    ease
                    select-none
                    hover:text-white hover:bg-indigo-600
                    focus:outline-none focus:shadow-outline
                  "
                  x-show="active == 2"
                >
                  LEARN MORE
                </button>
              </h1>
              <h1
                class="absolute text-5xl uppercase font-black tracking-widest"
                x-show="active == 3"
                x-transition:enter="transition ease-out duration-300"
                x-transition:enter-start="opacity-0 transform translate-y-12"
                x-transition:enter-end="opacity-100 transform translate-y-0"
                x-transition:leave="transition ease-out duration-300"
                x-transition:leave-start="opacity-100 transform translate-y-0"
                x-transition:leave-end="opacity-0 transform -translate-y-12"
              >
                but the majority have suffered alteration in some form
                <button
                  class="
                    border border-white
                    text-white
                    rounded-md
                    px-4
                    py-2
                    m-2
                    transition
                    duration-500
                    ease
                    select-none
                    hover:text-white hover:bg-indigo-600
                    focus:outline-none focus:shadow-outline
                  "
                  x-show="active == 3"
                >
                  LEARN MORE
                </button>
              </h1>
            </div>

            <div class="carousel col-start-1 row-start-1" x-ref="carousel">
              <div class="w-3/5 px-2">
                <img
                  src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1581375221876-8f287f7cd2cc?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=770&q=80"
                  loading="lazy"
                />
              </div>
              <div class="w-3/5 px-2">
                <img
                  src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1581375279144-bb3b381c7046?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=770&q=80"
                  loading="lazy"
                />
              </div>
              <div class="w-3/5 px-2">
                <img
                  src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1581375303816-4a17124934f7?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=770&q=80"
                  loading="lazy"
                />
              </div>
              <div class="w-3/5 px-2">
                <img
                  src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1494253109108-2e30c049369b?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=770&q=80"
                  loading="lazy"
                />
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div
          class="row-start-2 col-start-1"
          x-show="active == 1"
          x-transition:enter="transition ease-out duration-300"
          x-transition:enter-start="opacity-0 transform scale-90"
          x-transition:enter-end="opacity-100 transform scale-100"
          x-transition:leave="transition ease-in duration-300"
          x-transition:leave-start="opacity-100 transform scale-100"
          x-transition:leave-end="opacity-0 transform scale-90"
        ></div>
      </div>
    </main>
</body>

</html>
```

The reason why you're not able to apply hover effects to the button is because of a certain `pointer-events` property that has been set to `none`, on the div that contains the `<h1>` and `<button>` tags. This is because if it is not set as such, the drag functionality which is applied to the background will not work. So it's a choice between being able to click the button and highlight the heading text, or be able to drag and scroll the background.

If you remove the *pointer-events-none* class, you'll notice your hover effects working on the button.

**EDIT:**

Alright, so we're in part 2. Basically what we need to do is bring the buttons up to the level that the headers are in. When this page is rendered in the DOM, you can inspect the elements using DevTools. I copied the button elements from the DOM, and put them in the same container as all the `<h1>` tags. So now you have 2 sets of buttons. This is what one set looks like:

```
<button class="flickity-button flickity-prev-next-button previous custom-flickity-button" type="button" aria-label="Previous" onclick="slide('previous')">
  <svg class="flickity-button-icon" viewBox="0 0 100 100">
    <path d="M 10,50 L 60,100 L 70,90 L 30,50  L 70,10 L 60,0 Z" class="arrow"></path>
  </svg>
</button>
<button class="flickity-button flickity-prev-next-button custom-flickity-button next" type="button" aria-label="Next" onclick="slide('next')">
  <svg class="flickity-button-icon" viewBox="0 0 100 100">
    <path d="M 10,50 L 60,100 L 70,90 L 30,50  L 70,10 L 60,0 Z" class="arrow" transform="translate(100, 100) rotate(180) "></path>
  </svg>
</button>
```

A little digging through the Flickity docs, and you find out that the buttons are [optional](https://flickity.metafizzy.co/options.html#prevnextbuttons), for rendering. Similarly, since we won't be directly interacting with the Flickity instance, I've disabled the drag features at the time of initialization. This looks like this:

```js
function carousel() {
    return {
      active: 0,
      init() {
        var flkty = new Flickity(this.$refs.carousel, {
          wrapAround: true,
          draggable: false, // This is new
          prevNextButtons: false // This is new
        });
        flkty.on("change", (i) => (this.active = i));
      }
    };
  }
```

Since the new buttons we've added are basically the ones Flickity uses, we don't really need to worry too much about styling. Just some slight modification is needed. To reduce the chances of accidentally modifying the actual CSS, I've added a class `custom-flickity-button`.

The additional styling:

```css
  .custom-flickity-button {
    /* 21 is the threshold. Below this, it will be under the h1 text */
    z-index: 25;
  }

  .custom-flickity-button:focus {
    outline: none;
    box-shadow: none;
  }

  /* 
  If you make h1 relative, then this padding will apply. 
  But that was causing some issues while transitioning. 
  I'm leaving this for you to explore. 
  */
  #text-container {
    padding: 0 70px;
  }
```

Finally, we needed to give the new buttons some click functionality:

```js
// This is to make the new buttons slide. You can modify the logic to work with multiple carousels, as you've done above
  function slide(value) {
    let flkty = Flickity.data(document.querySelector('.carousel'))
    if (value == 'next') {
      flkty.next()
    } else if (value == 'previous') {
      flkty.previous()
    }
  }
```

I'm not too familiar with using Alpine and Tailwind, so you could probably modify this code to fit it with that. But anyway, here's what you asked for. Interactive *Learn More* button with interactive slider buttons.

```js
function carousel() {
        return {
            active: 0,
            init() {
                var flkty = new Flickity(this.$refs.carousel, {
                    wrapAround: true,
                });
                flkty.on("change", (i) => (this.active = i));
            },
        };
    }

    function carouselFilter() {
        return {
            active: 0,
            changeActive(i) {
                this.active = i;

                this.$nextTick(() => {
                    let flkty = Flickity.data(
                        this.$el.querySelectorAll(".carousel")[i]
                    );
                    flkty.resize();

                    console.log(flkty);
                });
            },
        };
    }
    
      // This is to make the new buttons slide. You can modify the logic to work with multiple carousels, as you've done above
  function slide(value) {
    let flkty = Flickity.data(document.querySelector('.carousel'))
    if (value == 'next') {
      flkty.next()
    } else if (value == 'previous') {
      flkty.previous()
    }
  }
```

```css
.flickity-viewport {
      height: 500px !important;
    }

    h1 > button {
      position: absolute !important;
      left: 0;
      top: 100%;
      font-size: 1rem !important;
    }
    
    .custom-flickity-button {
    /* 21 is the threshold. Below this, it will be under the h1 text */
    z-index: 1
  }

  .custom-flickity-button:focus {
    outline: none;
    box-shadow: none;
    border: none;
  }
      /* 
  If you make h1 relative, then this padding will apply. 
  But that was causing some issues while transitioning. 
  I'm leaving this for you to explore. 
  */
  #text-container {
    padding: 0 70px;
  }
```

```html
<html>

<head></head>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/flickity@2/dist/flickity.pkgd.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/alpinejs/alpine@v2.x.x/dist/alpine.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/flickity@2/dist/flickity.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/tailwindcss@1.2.0/dist/tailwind.min.css">

<body>
    <main class="min-h-screen bg-black text-white flex items-center justify-center" x-data="carouselFilter()">
    <div class="container grid grid-cols-1">
      <div class="flex py-12 justify-center">
        <a class="
              px-2
              text-lg
              uppercase
              font-bold
              tracking-widest
              hover:text-white
            " :class="{ 'text-gray-800': active != 0 }" href="#" @click.prevent="changeActive(0)">Lorem Ipsum</a>
      </div>

      <div class="row-start-2 col-start-1" x-show="active == 0" x-transition:enter="transition ease-out duration-300"
        x-transition:enter-start="opacity-0 transform scale-90" x-transition:enter-end="opacity-100 transform scale-100"
        x-transition:leave="transition ease-in duration-300" x-transition:leave-start="opacity-100 transform scale-100"
        x-transition:leave-end="opacity-0 transform scale-90">
        <div class="grid grid-cols-1 grid-rows-1" x-data="carousel()" x-init="init()">
          <div class="
                col-start-1
                row-start-1
                relative
                z-20
                flex
                items-center
                justify-center
              " id="text-container">
            <button class="flickity-button flickity-prev-next-button previous custom-flickity-button" type="button"
              aria-label="Previous" onclick="slide('previous')"><svg class="flickity-button-icon" viewBox="0 0 100 100">
                <path d="M 10,50 L 60,100 L 70,90 L 30,50  L 70,10 L 60,0 Z" class="arrow"></path>
              </svg></button>
            <button class="flickity-button flickity-prev-next-button custom-flickity-button next" type="button"
              aria-label="Next" onclick="slide('next')"><svg class="flickity-button-icon" viewBox="0 0 100 100">
                <path d="M 10,50 L 60,100 L 70,90 L 30,50  L 70,10 L 60,0 Z" class="arrow"
                  transform="translate(100, 100) rotate(180) "></path>
              </svg></button>
            <h1 class="absolute text-5xl uppercase font-black tracking-widest" x-show="active == 0"
              x-transition:enter="transition ease-out duration-300"
              x-transition:enter-start="opacity-0 transform translate-y-12"
              x-transition:enter-end="opacity-100 transform translate-y-0"
              x-transition:leave="transition ease-out duration-300"
              x-transition:leave-start="opacity-100 transform translate-y-0"
              x-transition:leave-end="opacity-0 transform -translate-y-12">
              Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting
              industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy
              text ever since the 1500s
              <button class="
                    border border-white
                    text-white
                    rounded-md
                    px-4
                    py-2
                    m-2
                    transition
                    duration-500
                    ease
                    select-none
                    hover:text-white hover:bg-indigo-600
                    focus:outline-none focus:shadow-outline
                  " x-show="active == 0">
                LEARN MORE
              </button>
            </h1>

            <h1 class="absolute text-5xl uppercase font-black tracking-widest" x-show="active == 1"
              x-transition:enter="transition ease-out duration-300"
              x-transition:enter-start="opacity-0 transform translate-y-12"
              x-transition:enter-end="opacity-100 transform translate-y-0"
              x-transition:leave="transition ease-out duration-300"
              x-transition:leave-start="opacity-100 transform translate-y-0"
              x-transition:leave-end="opacity-0 transform -translate-y-12">
              It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted
              by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout.
              <button class="
                    border border-white
                    text-white
                    rounded-md
                    px-4
                    py-2
                    m-2
                    transition
                    duration-500
                    ease
                    select-none
                    hover:text-white hover:bg-indigo-600
                    focus:outline-none focus:shadow-outline
                  " x-show="active == 1">
                LEARN MORE
              </button>
            </h1>
            <h1 class="absolute text-5xl uppercase font-black tracking-widest" x-show="active == 2"
              x-transition:enter="transition ease-out duration-300"
              x-transition:enter-start="opacity-0 transform translate-y-12"
              x-transition:enter-end="opacity-100 transform translate-y-0"
              x-transition:leave="transition ease-out duration-300"
              x-transition:leave-start="opacity-100 transform translate-y-0"
              x-transition:leave-end="opacity-0 transform -translate-y-12">
              There are many variations of passages of Lorem Ipsum available
              <button class="
                    border border-white
                    text-white
                    rounded-md
                    px-4
                    py-2
                    m-2
                    transition
                    duration-500
                    ease
                    select-none
                    hover:text-white hover:bg-indigo-600
                    focus:outline-none focus:shadow-outline
                  " x-show="active == 2">
                LEARN MORE
              </button>
            </h1>
            <h1 class="absolute text-5xl uppercase font-black tracking-widest" x-show="active == 3"
              x-transition:enter="transition ease-out duration-300"
              x-transition:enter-start="opacity-0 transform translate-y-12"
              x-transition:enter-end="opacity-100 transform translate-y-0"
              x-transition:leave="transition ease-out duration-300"
              x-transition:leave-start="opacity-100 transform translate-y-0"
              x-transition:leave-end="opacity-0 transform -translate-y-12">
              but the majority have suffered alteration in some form
              <button class="
                    border border-white
                    text-white
                    rounded-md
                    px-4
                    py-2
                    m-2
                    transition
                    duration-500
                    ease
                    select-none
                    hover:text-white hover:bg-indigo-600
                    focus:outline-none focus:shadow-outline
                  " x-show="active == 3">
                LEARN MORE
              </button>
            </h1>
          </div>

          <div class="carousel col-start-1 row-start-1" x-ref="carousel">
            <div class="w-3/5 px-2">
              <img
                src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1581375221876-8f287f7cd2cc?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=770&q=80"
                loading="lazy" />
            </div>
            <div class="w-3/5 px-2">
              <img
                src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1581375279144-bb3b381c7046?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=770&q=80"
                loading="lazy" />
            </div>
            <div class="w-3/5 px-2">
              <img
                src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1581375303816-4a17124934f7?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=770&q=80"
                loading="lazy" />
            </div>
            <div class="w-3/5 px-2">
              <img
                src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1494253109108-2e30c049369b?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=770&q=80"
                loading="lazy" />
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div
    class="row-start-2 col-start-1"
    x-show="active == 1"
    x-transition:enter="transition ease-out duration-300"
    x-transition:enter-start="opacity-0 transform scale-90"
    x-transition:enter-end="opacity-100 transform scale-100"
    x-transition:leave="transition ease-in duration-300"
    x-transition:leave-start="opacity-100 transform scale-100"
    x-transition:leave-end="opacity-0 transform scale-90"
  ></div>
  </main>
</body>

</html>
```

PS: For some reason, `.custom-flickity-button:focus` is still showing a blue box-shadow in the snippet. It didn't show up normally, so you may want to look at that.

**EDIT 2:**

Hey! Just did some reading on the pointer-events property and it turns out that if you set `pointer-events: none` to an element, but give a value of `pointer-events: auto` to any of its children, the parent element will not block the pointer events from triggering on the children.

Basically what this means is that everything I did in Edit 1 was unnecessary. All you need to do is add an extra line of CSS to the buttons in my original answer -> `pointer-events: auto`, and you will have both usable buttons and a draggable carousel!

This is good! It solves your issue, and both you and I learned something new today! :P

I've made this change in my original snippet, so you can look at it there. As for Edit 1, I'll leave it as it is for now. Might help someone some other time, who knows.

Comment: Thank you Omar for solving the CSS issue to make the button appear correctly! Makes a lot of sense given the `pointer-events-none`. Speaking of this class however, does that mean this button does not actually work? I don't mind the hover effects, but I'm afraid that the button does not actually have any click event? As in the carousel slide maneuver is overriding the button from being usable.

Comment: Note that I also tested with z-index to try and lift the elements above the carousel drag maneuver.

Comment: I don't think z-index will work in that manner. I may be wrong, but from what I remember reading about z-index, it only works on elements on the same level. If we have 2 containers B and C sitting inside a container  A, and suppose C has a child element D nested a few levels deep. Applying Z index on D will only bring it up or down relative to other elements on its level. You will not be able to render D above B, if B is above C. I could be wrong about this, it's best if you confirm this behaviour once, but I do remember reading something along these lines some time ago.

Comment: My advice would be to either have the Learn More button be in the same container as the left and right buttons, so that they can be interacted with together. Or, move the left and right arrow buttons up a few levels and have them be in the same container as the headings+button. The second option would be better, as we need the 'Learn More' button to be nested inside the heading to get its relative position.

Comment: I'm a little confused, I understand your suggestions, but I'm having trouble implementing them because the actual left/right icons are within the Flickity script which is used by my `carousel()` variable. Would be able to show me how you mean for me to implement this above in your original answer?

Comment: Thank you so much for the help. So I guess it comes down to having a usable button vs a draggable carousel?

Comment: @woof You don't need to choose between the 2 anymore. Your issue's been solved :)

Comment: Thank you Omar for your kind help! You have saved me hours of work.